# Open or Save a file window in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm having the following problem in Selenium IDE.
I have a page of my system, where I export reports in PDF format. 
It happens that when I click the "Export" button, the system opens a window indicating if I want to save or open the file.

At this point the case logically fails, since I can not find a way to open it or save it.
I have tried with commands like "selectpopup" and "chooseokonnextconfirmation" and it did not work.

How can I do it ???

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that you can't Selenium IDE cannot interact with the open/save dialogs. Your best bet would be to change firefox's default behaviour when clicking on PDFs. If you go to settings > applications, there should be a list with various application/file types. If you find PDF you can change it to always save the file, without the window prompt

Comment: Selenium interacts with fresh instance of the browser so i don't think the settings will be retained on a selenium controlled instance.